# Xampp will not connect to MYsql database or ProFTPD

Tags: mysql, database, apache, server, xampp

getting this error when trying to connect t xampp i have uninstalled then re -installed agin but still no luck i do not know what it could be any help appreciated
im using a mac high sierra 
i dont know if a app little snitch may be blocking connection although i cant seem to see anything plus all was fine yesterday until i done a chmod to give permission for images.
mow today i can not conncet to the MySql server and now that i have re-installed it will not connect to the ProFTPD either
i deleted that old xampp folder as i though it may be that but and was planning to just start agin but no luck.

[php my admin errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvybg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your configs first, username, password and port. Usually mySQL uses port 3306, so check it also and if no other application is using the same port.
By the way check if mysqli module is installed and/or activated.

Comment: Thank you for your response Pedro.. i ended up cheating and taking the easy way out though...  i got annoyed trying and just deleted xampp and ended up installing mamp instead.

Comment: Hi matteveli, I found the answer, you'd have to go to phpmyadmin folder, to config.inc.php and change the first lines of the $cfg array, Line 19 in most cases, and fill it in properly. Anyway, you did good installing Mamp in your case, since you're in a Mac